# Is $b^{m+1} = O(b^m)$

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

For $b$ and $m$ being variables, is it the case that $b^{m+1} = O(b^m)$ ?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $$O(f(x))=g(x)\implies|f(x)|\le Mg(x)$$Where $M$ is a number and $x>x_0$ for some number $x_0$. Now, putting in $b^m$: $$O(b^m)=g(b)\implies|b^m|\le Mg(b)$$If we put $g(x)=b^{m+1}$, $M>0$, and $x_0=\dfrac{1}{M}$, then the condition holds.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused with this answer - I think this may be addressing the case of single variable asymptotic notation, but I'm talking about the case where b itself is a variable too?

Comment: @AbhishekManikandan I see what you mean. But it doesn't matter what $b$ is.